# How to match C# sort with HANA sort order for alphanumeric column

Tags: c#, hana

I have a requirement to compare data between C# List of object (which is sorted with C# method orderby ) with HANA database. I have noticed that sort order for alphanumeric column is different between C# and HANA. Is there any way to change C# sort to match with HANA sorting logic.

Comment: Use a custom IComarable<t> : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1?force_isolation=true&view=net-6.0

Comment: @jdweng I don't know what logic HANA database uses for sorting so how can I implement using this option?

Comment: If YOU don't know what sort order is, how do you expect to implement it?   Maybe check the HANA web site?

Comment: Are you reading the HANA data into a C# model?  If so, why not just sort the HANA data in C# using the same sorting function that you use on the List?

Comment: @JohnGlenn Sending C# list in Odata feed to HANA and HANA has logic to compare data. Looking for option to sort C# data similar to HANA before sending it. Due to some limitation it can't be done at HANA end.